# Simple Spring/Hibernate app permanently fails to startup within 45 to 600 seconds

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I made a simple webapp from Websystique's "Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations" tutorial.

It did two things for deployment:

1. Eclipse's built-in Tomcat deployment
2. Manually put the war file into `tomcat-location/webapps`, use `tomcat-location/startup.sh` and go to `localhost:8080`

For number 2, I just started at a blank webpage that never loaded.

For number 1, as it is a known issue here, I have tried the following possible solutions and **none** has resolved my issue:

1. Removed all breakpoints
2. Increased the Tomcat timeouts (I used 45, 100, 300 and 600)
3. Removed the current Tomcat server and created a new one, removing the old's settings [as suggested here](https://sansatechnology.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/how-to-fix-eclipse-tomcat-not-starting-in-45-seconds/)
4. Restarted Eclipse and my system

This problem is now beyond my current knowledge. The logs are always stuck in

```
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

with the Progress stuck in:

```
Preparing launch delegate...:
```

Please help what could have been the cause of this.

---

Below are logs that could help:

### `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring4MVCHibernateDemo Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.2 has been relocated to org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to /Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Spring4MVCHibernateDemo] in [/Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/target/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [225 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/target/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Spring4MVCHibernateDemo ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/target/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo.war to /Users/username/.m2/repository/com/websystique/springmvc/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /Users/username/Projects/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/pom.xml to /Users/username/.m2/repository/com/websystique/springmvc/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Spring4MVCHibernateDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.124 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-14T19:37:57+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Eclipse Run As Server:

```
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Spring4MVCHibernateDemo' did not find a matching property.
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.4
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 6 2016 08:43:30 UTC
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.4.0
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.11.6
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/username/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/username/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/username/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/endorsed
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/username/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1035 ms
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.4
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:21 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.springmvc.configuration.AppInitializer@745a5afb]
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Aug 14 20:00:21 PHT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class com.springmvc.configuration.AppConfiguration]
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:22 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:23 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:23 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 14, 2016 8:00:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

### `HibernateConfiguration.java`

```
package com.springmvc.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.springmvc.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.springmvc.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

### `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.websystique.springmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring4MVCHibernateDemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring4MVCHibernateDemo Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>Spring4MVCHibernateDemo</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <finalName>Spring4MVCHibernateDemo</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

## Additional logs:

### [`mvn -X clean install`](http://pastebin.com/V6m0wxuL)

---

There was a warning about `hibernate.properties` being not found

```
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

but in the tutorial this was set via

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
```

wherein `application.properties` was saved under `/Java Resources/src/main/resources`.

Also I tried having MySQL running and not running during Tomcat run but this did not help either.

Comment: could you change your log properties and put hibernate and spring loggers to debug to see what is exactly being processed at the time of the delay. For some reason i suspect that it tries to connect with a not-configured well DB.